# Finding a non-maximal ideal which is comaximal with $(x^2)$ in the polynomial ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

I'm struggling with the following question:

> Find an example of a proper ideal in the real-valued polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$ which is *not* maximal, but is co-maximal with the ideal $(x^2)$.

I know that the ideals $I$ and $J$ in a ring $R$ are co-maximal if $I+J = R$. Also, I know that if an ideal contains a unit, say $1$, then it must be equal to the entire ring.

So, by putting $I = (x^2) I$ need to find an ideal $J$ which satisfies the aforementioned conditions s.t. $1$ is expressible as a linear combination of elements of $I$ and $J$.

Am I on the right track? I guess my main issue is understanding which elements are maximal in the polynomial ring and which aren't.

---

Comment: You are on the right track! See if you can think of a (degree two) polynomial $g$ in $R[x]$ for which $\alpha x^2 + \beta g = 1$, for some $\alpha,\beta \in R$.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I understand this now.f I put g(x) = x^2 -1, then x^2 - (x^2 -1) = 1, so 1 is contained in the sum of the ideals and they are co-maximal. To argue that (x^2 -1) is not maximal, could I just say since R(x) is a PID every prime ideal must be maximal, but x^2 -1 is reducible so the ideal its generates can' be prime?

Comment: At the end, you argue every prime ideal must be maximal, and $(x^2-1)$ is not prime but these together don't necessarily imply $(x^2-1)$ is not maximal. Otherwise, you're correct.